# Android devices getting slower over time

Tags: 8.1-oreo, lagging

At work we have a bunch of Casio handheld android terminals (DT-X400). They do not have any connectivity to the internet (so no updates), almost all apps are disabled except for those we use for work. We used them for about a year, and recently got a few more.

When we started using the new ones, we discovered that they perform a way, way better:

- no lag;
- navigating within applications is fast and smooth;

while the others feels sluggish:

- it takes few minutes to boot up;
- often it lags while doing simple actions, like scrolling on small lists;
- opening apps takes a long time (> 30 seconds for calculator) - when you click on the app icon it looks like it freezes, then after a while screen goes black and after few more seconds app opens up.

The new ones performs a lot better when doing same tasks.
They are all the same model, hardware is the same, drivers versions on every device are also the same. All of these terminals runs Android 8.1.
I tried clearing memory, disabling all the apps I can, later did a factory reset, but performance did not improved.

So my questions are:

- **What can cause such slowdowns of android devices?**
- **Is there any way to improve performance, without getting root access?**

**Update:**
As of the suggestions in the question comments, I have tried swapping bateries from the new devices to the old ones and also powering them completely off. Neither option showed any performance improvements.

I am also aware about aging flash memory, after the weekend I will try to run some test on both devices to compare memory performance and update my question with the results and methods used.

Comment: Do you keep the devices always on or do you shutdown them when not in use? How good is the battery of the old devices compared to the new devices? When it comes to performance slowdown because of hardware only flash memory (flash memory can get slower it it is written to very often) and defect cooling system because of physical defects (e.g. by bending the device) come into my mind.

Comment: @Robert Devices are always on, for few of them we have bought new batteries two months earlier, and they hold the charges pretty good. Still, as they are easily changeable I will try putting the new ones into the old devices just in case it is causing problems.

As for the memory - it may be, the one app we use has a SQLite database that is often written. Also, the app creates about 20 .txt files every day with an average size of 20KB. Maybe there is way to check it?

As for the physical defects, the devices only have some scratches but there is no visible physical damages.

Comment: Then may be you should try to shut down them for a few minutes. I recently had to learn that it sometime makes a big difference between rebooting a device and shutdown and later turn it on again (internally some chips get a "hard reboot" as they are not powered anymore). Not sure if it makes a difference but worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will try shutting them down completely. Later I will post the results.

Comment: After powering two of the devices off for 10 minutes, and taking batteries out nothing have changed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why a phone gets slower as time passes?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/53757/why-a-phone-gets-slower-as-time-passes)

Comment: @beeshyams Thanks for the link, it explains about TRIM support (which in my case is supported) and about aging flash memory (which I believe is causing my problem). But I still hope somebody can suggest other possible causes or tips for improving devices performance.